# Loop by variable names

Tags: r

I want to create a for loop by variable names.

Each time, I calculte the max between each two variables, and define a new one in data `df`. New variables look like this:`var1_1`, `var1_2`... Here is my code:

```
 df=data.frame(matrix(c(1:6), nrow = 2))
 colnames(df) = c("x", "y", "z")

 for(i in length(names(df))-1){
   df = df %>% mutate(paste0("var", i, "_", i+1) = max(names(df)[i], names(df)[i+1]))
}
```

But there gives error.

Expected output:

```
>df
 x     y     z    var1_2    var1_3   var2_3
 1     3     5      3         5        5
 2     4     6      4         6        6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a Loop you can try:

```
 ind<-combn(3,2)
 for(i in 1:dim(df)[2]){
    i <- ind[,i]
    name <- paste0("var", i[1], "_", i[2])
    val <- names(df)[i[ifelse(sum(df[,i[1]]) > sum(df[,i[2]]),1,2)]]
    df <- mutate_(df, .dots= setNames(list(val),name))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way via base R,

```
m1 <- sapply(combn(names(df),2, simplify = FALSE), function(i) do.call(pmax, df[i]))
nms <- combn(ncol(m1), 2, function(i) paste0('Var', i[1], '_', i[2]))

cbind(df, setNames(data.frame(m1), nms))
#  x y z Var1_2 Var1_3 Var2_3
#1 1 3 5      3      5      5
#2 2 4 6      4      6      6
```

Comment: Is possible that using loops instead of sapply? Actually,  I only want to use loops.

Comment: Not really familiar with for-loops. But why do you want loops?